# Qt QTableView top-to-bottom flow

Tags: qt, qtableview

I have a grid that's display using a control that inherits from QTableView. Right now the grid is displayed left-to-right and then as things overflow, it goes to the next row like this

```
 -----------
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
|------------
| 4 |   |   |
|------------
|   |   |   |
 -----------
```

but I want it to go top-to-bottom first and then as things overflow, it should go to next column like this

```
 -----------
| 1 | 4 |   |
|------------
| 2 |   |   |
|------------
| 3 |   |   |
 -----------
```

I'm mostly a .Net developer and it's pretty trivial with .net winforms controls, but how do I get `QTableView` to do this?

Thanks

Comment: There's a solution at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21653253/how-to-change-orientation-of-qt-tableview

Answer (score 3):

The data displayed is a function of your model.  The best way to change the behavior is to create a proxy [QAbstractTableModel](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/qabstracttablemodel.html) that swaps the rows and the columns. How complicated this will be will be dependent on your current model. It almost sounds like you have a linear model and that the view just presents it in a table-like fashion in which case you're probably using the wrong model.

If you really do have a linear model, consider using [QAbstractListModel](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/qabstractlistmodel.html) and [QListView](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/qlistview.html). The QListView then has a [flow](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/qlistview.html#flow-prop) property that will allow you to choose between left-to-right and top-to-bottom.